# Nuxt FATAL Cannot set property 'stage' of undefined error

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

Nuxt FATAL  Cannot set property 'stage' of undefined error

Anyone faced this issue on Nuxt FATAL  Cannot set property 'stage' of undefined error

When I upgrade node 12.16.1 to 14.18.0 it's returning nuxt fatal error.

Do you have any idea or solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` to version "5.3.2" was the solution for me.
That version isn't the latest version at this date but it didn't require any upgrade steps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I cam across the same error and the answer [Tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76781455/1589619) gave below pointed me in the right direction.

What I did was look at the `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` [changelog](https://github.com/nuxt-modules/tailwindcss/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) and saw where there was a breaking change for my `tailwind` version and what they recommended was adding a peer dependency as you can see [here](https://github.com/nuxt-modules/tailwindcss/pull/270)

Then using the [changelog](https://github.com/nuxt-modules/tailwindcss/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) I found which version would still be compatible with my nuxt and tailwind versions